# Solr - removing special characters

Tags: solr, indexing, information-retrieval

a pretty basic question but can anyone tell me how to remove special characters from documents while indexing in solr? I went through Solr wiki but couldn't find anything relevant. I saw few tokenizers like WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory and StandardTokenizerFactory. I am using WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory in my schema.xml but it doesn't seem to solve the purpose. I am still able to query using "*" and "-" etc.

Comment: which special characters you want to remove?

Comment: @Mysterion Like *, -, ?, \n etc

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the standard tokenizer:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
```

It should remove the characters you have mentioned.

Once the words have been tokenized you may apply further processing, like splitting on case change and numerics, using the WordDelimiterFilterFactory for better matching.

Also, very useful almost all the time when dealing with schema configuration, is the solr's analysis page. It gives you a lot of valuable feedback.